# How can I install KateSql plugin on ubuntu?

Tags: kate

I just installed `kate` by typing

```
sudo apt-get install kate
```

Now I want to install this [kate sql plugin](http://kate-editor.org/2010/07/29/katesql-a-new-plugin-for-kate/) and google is not helping me.

I downloaded a punch of files from [here](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Kate+SQL+Plugin?content=126861)

- But what should I do with these files?
- Where should I put them?
- Would you please tell me how can I install this?

Thanks

Comment: Please [do not cross-post between Stack Exchange sites](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq). You can ask your question here or [at Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30270/how-can-i-install-katesql-plugin-on-ubuntu), but not both. Since you're specifically after an answer on Ubuntu, I'm voting to close your question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install plugins directly inside Kate:

> Settings → Configure → Select Application → Plugins

You should see the SQL plugin there.